# Attach a vCard to an e-mail directly from a link on a website

Tags: email, vcf-vcard

I have (what I'm pretty sure is) a somewhat strange request from a client. What I'm gathering from her is that she wants a vCard made with her business card image, and she wants it attached to an e-mail. There is quite a bit of info on this topic to be found.

However, what I cannot find any info on, is the next part. What I think is that she wants the vCard to be automatically attached to a blank e-mail, from a link (icon) on her website. Is this even possible?

I know that typically vCards are used as your personal info/business card and you would use them to sign your own e-mail, etc with them. Not have someone else be sending them in an e-mail from your website...? Any ideas????!

Thanks in advance... any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: If you're talking about a mailto: link then no, it's not possible.  You could do it if you had a form that posted the email content back to the server and you sent the email using an smtp server you had access to.  But it is odd to attach a vCard to someone else's email.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. When you say a form that posted the email content back to the server - do you mean it would in fact end up coming up in the e-mail body as a vCard? Either way, it seems very unorthodox and a coding nightmare..?